# SmartGwt - Load Grid Data From JSON

Tags: smartgwt

I am trying to get started with SmartGwt. I am using the XJSONDatasource to make a cross-domain call to an example page at SmartClient that has JSON data. When I run the code, however, a popup comes up that says "Finding Records that match your criteria..." This never goes away, and the data is not loaded. I am using the free version of SmartGwt (my company has said that this is what we'll use). Hoping I'm just missing something obvious.

```
    DataSource dataSource = new XJSONDataSource();
    dataSource.setDataTransport(RPCTransport.SCRIPTINCLUDE);
    dataSource.setDataFormat(DSDataFormat.JSON);

    dataSource.setDataURL("http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/data/dataIntegration/json/contactsData.js");
    DataSourceTextField nameField = new DataSourceTextField("name", "name");

    nameField.setValueXPath("name");

    dataSource.setFields(nameField);

    ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
    grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
    grid.setWidth100();
    grid.setHeight(100);
    grid.setAutoFetchData(true);
    grid.draw();
```

Comment: You should tag this question with X-JSON as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see from the docs here: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/XJSONDataSource.html

> Note, as indicated in the tutorial
>   above, the server is responsible for
>   writing out not just the data, but
>   also a JavaScript function call that
>   tells the client that the response has
>   arrived. The client passes the name of
>   the function to call as the "callback"
>   URL parameter.

But there is no such callback in the code at the page you link at www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/data/dataIntegration/json/contactsData.js

Answer (score 3):

When your smartGWT datasource makes a call to this URL:

```
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/data/dataIntegration/json/contactsData.js
```

(If you data source is making a call to a Java App go to the bottom of this answer)

The request your datasource will make will include a GET parameter called callback which looks like this:

```
callback=isc.Comm._scriptIncludeReply_0
```

The script, contactsData.js, will need to capture this GET parameter.

contactsData.js will need to include a library to retrieve parameters from the URL:

javascript retrieve parameters function:

```
function getParameter ( queryString, parameterName ) {
   // Add "=" to the parameter name (i.e. parameterName=value)
   var parameterName = parameterName + "=";
   if ( queryString.length > 0 ) {
      // Find the beginning of the string
      begin = queryString.indexOf ( parameterName );
      // If the parameter name is not found, skip it, otherwise return the value
      if ( begin != -1 ) {
         // Add the length (integer) to the beginning
         begin += parameterName.length;
         // Multiple parameters are separated by the "&" sign
         end = queryString.indexOf ( "&" , begin );
      if ( end == -1 ) {
         end = queryString.length
      }
```

jQuery retrieve parameters function

```
http://ajaxcssblog.com/jquery/url-read-request-variables/
```

After you get the value of the callback parameter you will write the function name with the JSON as a parameter in the body of the response like so:

```
isc.Comm._scriptIncludeReply_0({"item": [ {"id": "1","name": "Monkey"}, 
{"id": "2","name": "Tree"}, 
{"id": "3","name": "Banana"} ] })
```

So the javascript code will look something like this:

```
Response.Write(getParameter(URLrequestFromDatasourceString,"callback") + " ( " + JSON + " )" );
```

---

**JAVA**

If your smartGWT datasource makes a call to a Java app URL:

http://www.smartclient.com/getJson.htm

Your Java controller will do the same thing but it is much easier

```
String callbackString = request.getParameter("callback");

response.setContentType("text/X-JSON");
response.getWriter().write( callbackString + " ( " + JSONstring + " ) " );
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
```

[Also, here is a link to a blog post on the issue](http://programminglinuxblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/smartgwt-cross-domain-json-data-source.html)